# How can i create a "twin" of a row and update just one value

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a little problem here.

I need to create 10 or more rows which are identically and then update just one column.

I will try a schema for my explanation.

I have this :

```
IDARRET        LBL              MODELE
1              Car              Ford
2              TRUCK            Ford
3              Boat             Ford
```

And i want something like this :

```
IDARRET        LBL              MODELE
1              Car              Ford
2              TRUCK            Ford
3              Boat             Ford
4              Car              Ferrari
5              Truck            Ferrari
6              Boat             Ferrari
```

I want it dynamic because i have more than 3 rows.

Sorry for my english, it's not my mother tongue, if you don't understand what i'm saying, please say it to me , i need to improve my englisk skill!

EDIT : After the question of axel : yes idarret is a sequence, i need to create a twin of all my rows and i choose the last value of the last column in my request.

Comment: Is `idarret` being set automatically, via a trigger and sequence? And how are you deciding which rows to duplicate, and what new value to use for the column?

Comment: For more details : yes the idarret is a sequence.
I need to duplicate ALL the row in my table .
The new value in the last column is choose by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you simply nou need an insert-select:

```
SQL> select * from test_twin;

   IDARRET LBL        MODELE
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Car        Ford
         2 TRUCK      Ford
         3 Boat       Ford

SQL> insert into test_twin
  2  select yourSequence.nextVal, LBL, 'Ferrari'
  3  from test_twin;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from test_twin;

   IDARRET LBL        MODELE
---------- ---------- ----------
         4 Car        Ferrari
         5 TRUCK      Ferrari
         6 Boat       Ferrari
         1 Car        Ford
         2 TRUCK      Ford
         3 Boat       Ford

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: or rather, `:user_input` instead of `'Ferrari'` to allow for user input. Anyway, very clean. Cool!

Comment: Oh thx it's look like easier than i thinked.
I wanted create a PL / SQL with a loop for this ^^

I stil have an error : duplicate primary key.

Comment: What fields does your PK contain? If it's only the ID, you should check the sequence

Comment: The PK only contain IDARRET.

Comment: that means that the values in table are greater than the sequence value; Maybe you could drop and re-create the sequence to start with the maximum existing value + 1